# how to map a dictionary values to another dictionary in a Pythonic way?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
source_dictionary = {
   "id": "1",
   "duration": "3",
   "start_time": "2020-08-31T12:22:11.8000000-0400",
   "end_time": "2020-08-31T12:24:36.8000000-0400",
   "customer_id": "123",
   "customer_extension": "123455",
   "customer_fullname": "John Doe",
   "call_reason": "complaint",
   "region": "NY",
   "company_number": "456",
   "language": "English",
   "company_phone_number": "999999",
   "customer_phone_number": "11111",
   "call_number": "20",
   "organization_name": "AAA",
   "company_name": "BBB"
   }
```

I want to create a new dictionary that renames a few keys, converts the value to integer for one of the key and apply a function to `start_time` and `end_time` and the rest of the key/value pairs remain the same.

The resulting dictionary is:

```
   {
   "duration": 3,
   "start_datetime": "2020-08-31T16:22:11.800000+00:00",
   "end_datetime": "2020-08-31T16:24:36.800000+00:00",
   "customer_id": "123",
   "customer_extension": "123455",
   "customer_full_name": "John Doe",
   "call_reason": "complaint",
   "region": "NY",
   "company_number": "456",
   "language": "English",
   "company_phone_number": "999999",
   "customer_phone_number": "11111",
   "call_number": "20",
   "organization_name": "AAA",
   "company_name": "BBB"
   }
```

My current code is:

```
    def convert_iso_to_utc(date_string):
        yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
        return yourdate.astimezone(timezone.utc).isoformat()

    new_dict = {}

    new_dict["duration"] = int(source_dict["duration"])
    new_dict["start_datetime"] = convert_iso_to_utc(source_dict["start_time"])
    new_dict["end_datetime"] = convert_iso_to_utc(source_dict["end_time"])
    new_dict["customer_id"] = source_dict["customer_id"]
    new_dict["customer_extension"] = source_dict["customer_extension"]
    new_dict["customer_full_name"] = source_dict["customer_fullname"]
    new_dict["call_reason"] = source_dict["call_reason"]
    new_dict["region"] = source_dict["region"]
    new_dict["company_number"] = source_dict["company_number"]
    new_dict["distributor_number"] = source_dict["distributor_number"]
    new_dict["language"] = source_dict["language"]
    new_dict["company_phone_number"] = source_dict["company_phone_number"]
    new_dict["call_number"] = source_dict["call_number"]
    new_dict["organization_name"] = source_dict["organization_name"]
    new_dict["company_name"] = source_dict["company_name"]
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: The Pydantic library is a great way to do this kind of stuff.  It casts variables to certain types, can parse from kwargs, a dict, or json, and can map incoming names to outgoing names.  It can be found here: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're more often than not copying the items in `source_dict`, and since you're doing the same operation on the datetime entries, you could do a loop:

```py
new_dict = {}

for key, value in source_dict.items():
    # "id" was left out in your example
    if key == "id":
        continue
    elif key == "duration":
        new_dict[key] = int(value)
    elif key in ("start_datetime", "end_datetime"):
        new_dict[key] = convert_iso_to_utc(value)
    else:
        new_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) the original dictionary and change the required values in the copied version.

```
new_dict = source_dict.copy()
new_dict["duration"] = int(new_dict["duration"])
new_dict["start_datetime"] = convert_iso_to_utc(new_dict["start_time"])
new_dict["end_datetime"] = convert_iso_to_utc(new_dict["end_time"])
```